# Theme support naming alignment

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, localization, dark-mode

As a first word I would say that this issue is related to Stack Overflow in Russian only, but implemention the fix for that should be done in general since the code is shared between all international SO sites.

A couple days ago support for black theme was enabled for international SO sites. In any language there is no issue with alignment:

- English

> [image: English]

- Portuguese (seems not completely translated yet)

> [image: Portuguese]

- Spanish

> [image: Spanish]

- Japanese

> [image: Japanese]

But not in Russian:

> [image: Russian]

Take a look at the middle option "System setting". Since this sentence is wider than icon itself text alignment on the center looks like as to the left alignment.

Can this alignment please be fixed for the strings that are larger than icon representing the current theme?

For instance I see something like this as final solution:

> [image: Solution]

Comment: in fact.. in spanish we have the same problem.. "Valor del sistema" was something we came up to avoid the problem.. but at least in spanish, is hard to translate the original meaning in such little space....

Comment: @gbianchi yep, this is a popular advice from SO team to fix the issue locally. My response to them "make flexible design".

Comment: There's a pull request to fix this. Once it's reviewed, it'll get deployed and I'll mark this as `status-completed`

Comment: @AaronShekey glad to hear that, I hope reviewer won't be too severe

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Review is just a formality... all my pull requests are perfection 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A fix for this has merged and will deploy at some point soon. It isn’t exactly as proposed, but it should be a better layout for longer international strings. Thanks for reporting!